# using the #id selector

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML/CSS for a few days mainly from W3Schools.

Could you please explain (or provide a reference) as to why the **div** has a black background, instead of orange? Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div#hello { background-color: black; }
      div { background-color: orange; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hello" style="height: 50px; width:50px" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called selector specificity. You target div#hello, more specific. The div selector beneath div#hello is a more general style, but you kind of overwrite the div style with the more specific div#hello style.

Although the div selector appears underneath the div#hello style, because of specificity, the div#hello selector is taken instead.

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/